# Генератор случайных чисел на Pysimplegui

Tags: python, gui, pysimplegui

пытаюсь сделать генератор случайных числел, но столкнулся с некоторыми проблемами. В общем я хочу вывести список чисел через функцию Gen(), но она работает не правильно, числа выводятся в терминал, а не в саму программу. Помогите пожалуйста

p.s с pysimplegui работаю недавно

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from random import *
 
def Gen():
    pass
 
sg.theme('SystemDefault') 
layout = [
 
          [sg.Text('Number of digits'), sg.Input(key = 'ND')],
          [sg.Text('Minimum'), sg.Input(key = 'Min')],
          [sg.Text('Maximum'), sg.Input(key = 'Max')],
          [sg.Text(' ', key = 'OUT')],
          [sg.Button('Generate'), sg.Button('Clear')] 
          ]
 
 
window = sg.Window('Generator', layout)
event,values = window.read()
 
def Gen():
    for i in range(1,int(values['ND'])):
        print(randint(int(values['Min']),int(values['Max'])), end = ' ') 
 
while True:
    event,values = window.read();
    if event is None or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    if event == 'Generate':
        window['OUT'].update(Gen())
    if event == 'Clear':
        window.FindElement('ND').Update('')
        window.FindElement('Min').Update('')
        window.FindElement('Max').Update('')
        window.FindElement('OUT').Update('')
```

Comment: А в какой виджет вы хотели вывести? Сейчас у вас выводится в консоль т.к. используете `print`. Значит, нужно вместо `print` помещать в виджет

Comment: Я не знаю как это сделать, можете подсказать как ?

Comment: Для начала замените print na return, и если часть кода которая отвечает за графический интерфейс правильная то все будет ок, если нет - читайте документацыю

Comment: @NIKI, добавил пример в ответ, если что-то непонятно, то не стесняйтесь спрашивать :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замечания и рекомендации:

1. Функция `Gen` не работала, т.к. по задумке она должна была возвращать значение, т.к. `window['OUT'].update(Gen())`
2. Код выполнялся только со второго раза, т.к. вне цикла вызывалось `event,values = window.read()`
3. Функции в питоне пишите с маленькой буквы
4. Добавил значения по-умолчанию в поля
5. Лучше избегайте глобальных переменных, у вас это была `values` в `Gen`
6. Функцию генерации сделал самодостаточной
7. Подправил импорты, т.к. рекомендуется такой порядок импортирования: системные библиотеки, внешние/установленные и собственные

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/44f7748ea7c41af3a4458ee623468da70062a91d/pysimplegui__examples/generation_random.py)

```
from random import randint

import PySimpleGUI as sg


sg.theme('SystemDefault')
layout = [
    [sg.Text('Number of digits'), sg.Input(default_text='5', key='ND')],
    [sg.Text('Minimum'), sg.Input(default_text='1', key='Min')],
    [sg.Text('Maximum'), sg.Input(default_text='9', key='Max')],
    [sg.Text(' ', key='OUT')],
    [sg.Button('Generate'), sg.Button('Clear')]
]

window = sg.Window('Generator', layout)


def generate(number: int, min_number: int, max_number: int) -> str:
    return ''.join(str(randint(min_number, max_number)) for _ in range(number))


while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event is None or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    if event == 'Generate':
        number, min_number, max_number = int(values['ND']), int(values['Min']), int(values['Max'])
        text = generate(number, min_number, max_number)
        print(text)
        window['OUT'].update(f'Result: {text}')

    if event == 'Clear':
        window.find_element('ND').update('')
        window.find_element('Min').update('')
        window.find_element('Max').update('')
        window.find_element('OUT').update('')
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, а как можно разделить вывод? Чтобы каждое число было отдельно, а не слитно

Comment: Ого, долго вас не было :D В функции generate в `''.join` использовать пробел, т.е. `' '.join`. С вам плюс и принять ответ ;)

Comment: спасибо большое))

Comment: @NIKI, пожалуйста :)